# How i can fix bootstrap card position backside. Actually my sidebar coming backside of the bootstrap card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

How I can fix the bootstrap card position backside. Actually my sidebar coming backside of the bootstrap card.

[image: How I can fix the bootstrap card position backside. Actually my sidebar coming backside of the bootstrap card.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your post to meet the guidelines. This will make it a lot easier for the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add z-index on your navbar on the mobile screen (media query) add this `z-index:999` in your navbar class (header)

```css
/***** Navbar ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 0 25px 30px;
  }
}

/*** not necessary ****/
.card {
  border: none !important;
}
.card img {
  max-height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar scroll</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Link
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-md-4 my-4">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654789460791-74c79093c37e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-4 my-4">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654789460791-74c79093c37e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-4 my-4">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654789460791-74c79093c37e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```